# date AND time being entered is 1 hr or day off under iOS/Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

This is really odd, the code below takes self.danceTimeIn (its text state) and converts it to an actual time.  The problem is that its coming up 1 hour LESS than what's entered.  Meaning that if I enter 14:03 I'll get 13:03 in the database!  The same thing is happening with the date version of this code

++++++++++++++++++++++

TIME

```
NSString *danceTimeIn = self.danceTimeIn.text;
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatIn = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormatIn setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate *timeIn = [timeFormatIn dateFromString: danceTimeIn];
```

DATE

```
NSString *danceDateValue = self.danceDate.text;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString: danceDateValue];
```

++++++++++++++++++++++

Anyone ???

Comment: I'm not a c programmer but could this be a default timezone sort of thing?

Comment: It's due to daylight saving time, I faced the same problem time ago. Don't remember the solution, but you can take this hint and google yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this. NSDateFormater change date according to locale of your device settings, if you set locale properlyl, you will get proper date. Try if this works :)

```
NSString *danceTimeIn = self.danceTimeIn.text;
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatIn = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormatIn setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[timeFormatIn setLocale:usLocale];
NSDate *timeIn = [timeFormatIn dateFromString: danceTimeIn];
```

Answer (score 1):

Time zone may be causing this problem.Try

```
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```

May be this will help.

Comment: Not unless he wants GMT. What he actually wants is local time.

Comment: Well, no I don't want local time.  What I want is the time that the user entered.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the timezone:-

first Check your local time zone

```
NSTimeZone *tz=[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
[dateformat setTimeZone:tz];
```

and then set your date accordingly.

Comment: This will convert given time to your time zone and not the actual date that is coming

Comment: I have updated the solution. Please follow now it is not checking, though it is setting the timezone